# Sails give 404 on get-parameters with "."

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have SPA sails app. All route i my SPA app, at first enter in welcome action controller.

```
'/*' :{
    controller : 'Web/welcomeController',
    skipAssets : true
}
```

All others routes using like api, for ajax request. This route '/*' using just for first render page. All others render provide angularjs. And there, one of route have get parameter with dot.

```
http://localhost:1337/search?lat=40.714545&long=-74.007112
```

And I get 404 error. All this is due to the parameter skipAsset, which ignores url with the content dot.

I need to controller also skip assets resource like image, js, ect. But correctly process requests with get parameters which content dot `/?lat=40.714545&long=-74.007112`

Comment: keep in mind this site is in English, consider finding someone to re-write your question. While it's more or less understandable by looking at the code and bits of your explanation, it doesn't make much sense, which will lower the chances for you to get help

Comment: remove the `skipAssets : true` in your controller for that route or make a new route to handle your search and not have `skipAssets : true` in it.

Comment: all others routes using like api, for ajax request. This route '/*' using just for first render page. All others render provide angularjs. So i need to controller also skip assets resource like image, js, ect. But correctly process requests such as this one `search?lat=40.714545&long=-74.007112`. Sorry for my bad english, try to re-write question.

Comment: I would suggest maybe a hack to modify sail's `node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:line 139` regex for finding the periods in the url. Maybe an additional conditional to a regex that would work for a url with lat && long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skipAssets` should probably be fixed to ignore the query string.  But in the meantime, you can use `skipRegex`instead of `skipAssets`.  From the [Sails.js docs on custom routes](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html?q=route-target-options):

> If skipping every URL containing a dot is too permissive, or you need
>   a route's handler to be skipped based on different criteria entirely,
>   you can use skipRegex. This option allows you to specify a regular
>   expression or array of regular expressions to match the request URL
>   against; if any of the matches are successful, the handler is skipped.
>   Note that unlike the syntax for binding a handler with a regular
>   expression, skipRegex expects actual RegExp objects, not strings.

So something like:

```
'/*' :{
    controller : 'Web/welcomeController',
    skipRegex : /^[^?]+\./
}
```

would probably be sufficient.